# Windows service and continuous memory alloc

Tags: windows, delphi, service, delphi-7

I have a windows service that launches a `Thread`. The service starts with `SYSTEM ACCOUNT`.

Inside the thread I use `CoInitialize`, because I have a XML object managed by an COM Object.

In some windows (7, 2008 std, not all) my service becomes to allocate memory continuous without any reason (12mb -> 50mb -> 100mb -> 500mb....) .

If I change the logon user of the service to a administrator user the problem stops. I cannot understand what is happening!

Using the Process Explorer (Microsoft sysinternals), I was able to see that some threads are freezed at `WaitForMultipleObjects` due a call of `DecodePointer` (kernel).

Here is the stack:

```
Start address: ntdll.dll!RtlDecodePointer+0x32a

ntkrnlpa.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xab7
ntkrnlpa.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x492
ntkrnlpa.exe!PsGetCurrentThreadTeb+0x377
ntkrnlpa.exe!KiCheckForKernelApcDelivery+0x24
ntkrnlpa.exe!IofCallDriver+0x64
ntkrnlpa.exe!NtQueryInformationProcess+0x1c63
ntkrnlpa.exe!NtQueryDirectoryFile+0x5b
ntkrnlpa.exe!ZwQueryLicenseValue+0xbc6
ntkrnlpa.exe!ZwQueryDirectoryFile+0x11
fltmgr.sys!FltGetVolumeName+0xd9
fltmgr.sys!FltCheckAndGrowNameControl+0x36a
fltmgr.sys!FltGetTunneledName+0xb81
fltmgr.sys!FltGetDestinationFileNameInformation+0x245
fltmgr.sys!FltReleaseFileNameInformation+0x871
fltmgr.sys!FltIsDirectory+0x58b
fltmgr.sys!FltGetFileNameInformation+0x120
fltmgr.sys!FltRequestOperationStatusCallback+0x635
fltmgr.sys!FltGetIrpName+0x80c
fltmgr.sys!FltGetIrpName+0xd42
fltmgr.sys!FltGetIrpName+0x13b3
fltmgr.sys!FltDeletePushLock+0x1db7
ntkrnlpa.exe!IofCallDriver+0x64
ntkrnlpa.exe!RtlUpcaseUnicodeChar+0x17e7
ntkrnlpa.exe!ObReferenceObjectByHandle+0x976
ntkrnlpa.exe!ObOpenObjectByName+0x13c
ntkrnlpa.exe!RtlUpcaseUnicodeChar+0x6c9
ntkrnlpa.exe!NtCreateFile+0x34
ntkrnlpa.exe!ZwQueryLicenseValue+0xbc6
ntdll.dll!KiFastSystemCallRet
shell32.dll!SHLoadInProc+0x7f3de
shell32.dll!SHLoadInProc+0x7f42c
shell32.dll!SHLoadInProc+0x7f7b5
shell32.dll!SHLoadInProc+0x7f8a5
shell32.dll!SHLoadInProc+0x37487
ntdll.dll!TpSetWait+0x149
ntdll.dll!RtlDecodePointer+0x32a
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36
```

Comment: it may relate to a error that occurs if the account is not an administrator and your application failing to deallocate memory in that case. (lack of proper try/finally constructs, maybe?)

Comment: Sounds like you have to do some debugging. What is the general-interest question you're asking Stack Overflow?

Comment: Rob: I'm looking for some direction, some information to help me to find the source of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your thread is likely not properly freeing the COM object(s) it creates.